# ADL with std::function: Can functions taking std::function objects be found via the types in the std::function's argument list?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std-function, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <functional>

namespace ns {
    struct Arg{};
    using Func = std::function<int(Arg)>;

    Func operator+(Func lhs, Func rhs) {
        return [lhs, rhs](Arg arg) {
            return lhs(arg) + rhs(arg);
        };
    }
}

int main() {
    ns::Func foo = [](ns::Arg i) {return 5;};
    ns::Func bar = [](ns::Arg i) {return 2;};
    auto foobar = foo + bar;
    return foobar(ns::Arg());
}
```

The above code compiles with various compilers. In contrast, the following code snippet does not compile. The only difference is the type of the argument used inside `Func` (`Arg` vs `int`):

```
#include <functional>

namespace ns {
    using Func = std::function<int(int)>;

    Func operator+(Func lhs, Func rhs) {
        return [lhs, rhs](int i) {
            return lhs(i) + rhs(i);
        };
    }
}

int main() {
  ns::Func foo = [](int i) {return i + 5;};
  ns::Func bar = [](int i) {return i * 2;};
  auto foobar = foo + bar; // BANG! Error here!
  return foobar(2);
}
```

I understand the error of the latter version: The called `operator+` is defined in a namespace and thus not found without explicit specification of the namespace. Argument dependent lookup will not help here, because the `operator+` is defined in a different namespace (`ns`) than the type of the argument (`std::function` is defined in `namespace std`, the `using` declaration is irrelevant for this).

But why is the correct `operator+` found in the case where `Func` takes an argument `ns::Arg`? The namespace of `Func` has not changed. Is the code using `Arg` valid according to the C++ standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the code using Arg valid according to the C++ standard?

It is. The associated namespaces for ADL include the associated namespaces of any template argument for a specialization, according to [[basic.lookup.argdep/2.2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#2.2)

> ... Furthermore, if T is a class template specialization, its
>   associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and
>   classes associated with the types of the template arguments provided
>   for template type parameters (excluding template template parameters);
>   the namespaces of which any template template arguments are members;
>   and the classes of which any member templates used as template
>   template arguments are members. [ Note: Non-type template arguments do
>   not contribute to the set of associated namespaces. — end note ]

`std::function<int(Arg)>` is a class template specialization, and `ns` is associated with one of its arguments. Therefore `ns` is included in the set of namespaces that is searched for `operator+` by ADL.

This rule exists to make reusable components more useful. The idea is to allow a library to expose say an API that takes a `std::unique_ptr<ns::Foo>` as a handle type, and for ADL to pick up the correct functions from `ns` when presented with a handle.